# Integration by parts: $\int xe^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a pretty straight forward integral to me, but I don't understand how my teacher got the answer:

$$(-xe^{-x})-e^{-x}+C$$

Here is the original problem:

$$\int xe^{-x}dx$$

Here are my steps to solve it:

$$u=x$$
$$du=dx$$
$$dv=e^{-x}dx$$
$$v=-e^{-x}$$

So rewriting the problem I get:

$$(-xe^{-x})- \int -e^{-x}dx$$

Solving the above integral I get (I factored out the negative one to get a positive $e^{-x}$):

$$(-xe^{-x})+e^{-x}+C$$

Did I solve this incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integrating $e^{-x}$ gives $-e^{-x}$. You're missing a minus sign at the final step.

Comment: Gosh all the back and forth in calculus 2 sometimes confuses me! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int xe^{-x}dx$$

$\displaystyle u=x\Rightarrow du=dx, dv=e^{-x}dx\Rightarrow v=-e^{-x}$.
So rewriting the problem we get:

$$\int xe^{-x}dx=(-xe^{-x})+ \int e^{-x}dx=(-xe^{-x})-e^{-x}+C $$

Answer (score 1):

[maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/)  confirms the solution of your teacher

```
(%i1) diff((-x*exp(-x))-exp(-x)+C,x);
                                        - x
(%o1)                               x %e
```

Your first step is  ok.

```
(%i2) diff((-x*exp(-x))-integrate(-exp(-x),x),x);
                                      - x
(%o2)                               x %e
```

Your final result is wrong

```
(%i3) diff((-x*exp(-x))+exp(-x)+C,x);
                                   - x       - x
(%o3)                          x %e    - 2 %e
```